# Can't install matplotlib on OS X with PIP

Tags: python, matplotlib, virtualenv, pip

This is my first time setting up matplotlib.
I'm on OS X Lion 10.7 (build 11A511s, so no updates done to the initial release of OS X Lion).
I am using virtualenv and pip to do the installation.
I'm aware of the incompatibility with libpng 1.5, so I didn't just run "pip install matplotlib"... instead...
I tried running this from inside the virtualenv:

`pip install -e git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib#egg=matplotlib-dev`

Looks like it starts installing, but then I get this error:

```
/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/nltk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/
__multiarray_api.h:1532: warning: ‘int _import_array()’ defined but not used

lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/wy/s1jr354d4xx7dk0lpdpbpsbc0000gn/T/
/ccfNUhyq.out (No such file or directory)

error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /Users/sameerfx/.virtualenvs/nltk/bin/python -c "import setuptools; __file__=
'/Users/sameerfx/.virtualenvs/nltk/src/matplotlib/setup.py'; exec(compile(open(__file__
).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/sameerfx/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Update: I'm uploaded OS X to 10.7.2 (Build 11C74) and the exact problem remains. I have also posted to Matplotlin's mailing list, but no response yet.

Comment: Forget about installing matplotlib with the OS X Python. It can be done, but is ultra-painful. Either get yourself a copy of the Enthought Python Distribution or get a copy of Python 2.7 from python.org (or use MacPorts, it's all good). Then install setuptools and pip and you're good to go.

Comment: Cool, thanks Chinmay. I will retry tonight after doing a up-to-date Python 2.7 installation with MacPorts.

Comment: I was able to install matplotlib using your method on Mountain Lion. I am using Homebrew to manage things instead of MacPorts. I followed suggestions from `$brew doctor` and once warnings were resolved, your `pip install -e git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib#egg=matplotlib-dev` worked.

Comment: Chinmay: can you make your comment an answer? I would vote it up and I have a feeling it would get accepted

Comment: I'd like to mention that using `pip` to install matplotlib works on nowadays (2013) on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

**Three years later:**

You should use [anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) to install matplotlib (or numpy or pandas or scipy) if you're new to the process.  This suggestion applies for pretty much any platform too.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... unless you are bent on using `pip` and `virtualenv` to install, try this:

```
git clone git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
```

And build and install as usual with:

```
cd matplotlib
python setup.py install
```

See [this](http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#how-to-install) for more `matplotlib` installation help.